# Why does the matplotlib.pyplot.quiver documentation states incorrect order of U, V parameters?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

Before anything, here is Google Colab link to showcase the issue: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sq8Dn7wdNqbfRmz2SyQnj0MfRirxmneA?usp=sharing

Im using matplotlib to plot some gradient field generated with:

```
x,y = numpy.gradient(array_2d)
```

And noticed strange thing. Documentation states that to plot 2d field, you need to pass U (x) and V(y). Example:

```
plt.quiver(x, y)
```

But when I do so with Gaussian field, it is obvious that something is wrong, because the result plots arrows all around. But when I invert the order of parameters, example:

```
plt.quiver(y, x)
```

Results in expect perfect gradient field.

Im getting it wrong(documentation, code) or there is really some issue?

Dont forget to check Google Colab to better understant the case.

Answer (score 1):

The `quiver` function and its documentation are correct, you just mis-interpreted the output of the [`gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) function.

In the output, the first array (`np.gradient(gaussianMatrix)[0]`) is the gradient along the first axis (`axis=0` = rows of the array), which is the y-axis in matplotlib and the second array is for the second axis (`axis=1` = columns of the array), which is the x-axis in matplotlib.

This is also explained in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) (in the examples section after the third example):

> For two dimensional arrays, the return will be two arrays ordered by
> axis. In this example the first array stands for the gradient in rows
> and the second one in columns direction:

To be inline with the matplotlib documentation I recommend using `u` and `v` instead of `x` and `y` if you don't pass the arrow locations but just the directions. So your code should be:

```
v,u = numpy.gradient(array_2d)
plt.quiver(u, v)
```